What's the fastest way to excavate a 16x16 chunk from ground level to bedrock?
I've started a new world and i tried excavating this chunk out of boredom, just wondering if there is any other way i could try (faster way than a diamond pick at least) to finish mining this chunk

In some versions, the answer would probably be some kind of weird bug that can either delete everything at once cause a gigantic explosion. End crystals can cause each other to explode instantly, so if you got them all into the ground at the correct places somehow, the answer could in theory be a single tick. But really, I cannot think of anything realistic that is better than a grid of TNT dispensers for now. This could be a nice optimisation challenge, but it would have to be decided what counts as included in the time, since for example gathering hundreds of stacks of TNT takes a while.

@Joachim No, that question means "mining" as "obtaining minerals", not as "removing blocks".

@Joachim When people mine for diamonds, they usually have no fast tools yet, so every broken block costs time. Most of the answers there are about breaking the minimum amount of blocks, so the opposite of this question.

I mean.... the only thing faster than a diamond pick is a netherite pick, and the only thing faster than a netherite pick is an enchanted netherite pick... right? :D

Try:

Having all the right tools for the job (this usually should just be a Pickaxe and a Shovel)
Adding the Efficiency (faster mining) and Unbreaking (durability lasts longer; has a chance of not lowering) to your tools
Using a beacon with Haste (9 blocks for Level 1, 9+25+49+81=164 blocks for Level 2)
Using the highest possible tier tools for the job (Netherite)

(preferbally all at once)
Unfortunately with clearing blocks, there aren't really any shortcuts* other than to set-and-forget a TNT duper, which requires a fair bit of setup (especially the guardrails for the flying machine).
*not really a shortcut but at least is a messy, but automated and passive way of doing it.

You could search for a moss block (from a wandering trader or a lush cave biome) and try to spread it with bone meal (crafted out of bones from skeletons). The moss blocks will convert nearby stone to new moss blocks. By using a hoe you could farm the moss blocks really fast. Always keep some of the moss blocks and spread them again. Continue until you have mined the complete chunk.

You can look up TNT duplicators (vanilla mechanic). They infinitely generate primed TNT entities which is very useful for blasting holes. There're loads of ways to construct one, but most only require a dozen blocks and can generate multiple TNTs every second.

While this might answer the question, it would be helpful if you included more details about your suggested solution in the answer itself. Answers on Arqade must be self-contained, and shouldn't rely on you needing to go to an external site to obtain more information. You can include links in your answer, but only as a means of supporting information contained in the answer itself.
